# Gradle error with a dollar sign

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

Sorry for my english.

I'm trying to create a new project in the Android Studio with Gradle support, but I can't correctly build my project. There is a code:

```
Gradle 'SportManager' project refresh failed:
     Cause: startup failed:
     initialization script 'C:\Users\ponomarev\AppData\Local\Temp\ijinit6732759991667918700.gradle': 33: illegal string body character after dollar sign;
     solution: either escape a literal dollar sign "\$5" or bracket the value expression "${5}" @ line 33, column 20.
     String[] paths = ["/LOGGER-2/c$/Program Files/android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-tooling-extension.jar","/LOGGER-2/c$/Program Files/android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-tooling-extension-v1.9.jar","/LOGGER-2/c$/Program Files/android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-tooling-extension-v1.11.jar","/LOGGER-2/c$/Program Files/android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-tooling-extension-v1.12.jar"]
     ^
     1 error
```

'LOGGER-2' is computer's name in the network.

I see that Gradle don't understand literal dollar sign $ in the following expression: "/LOGGER-2/c$/Program Files/...". How I can fix it issue?

Answer (score 14):

`$` in a double-quoted String literal has a special meaning in Groovy - it's used for String interpolation. If you want a literal `$`, either use a single-quoted String literal (e.g. `'foo$bar'`), or escape the `$` with `\` (e.g. `"foo\$bar"`).

Comment: The main problem consists in the fact that Gradle get wrong path to the lib directory.

Wrong: "/LOGGER-2/c$/Program Files/...."
Correct: "/LOGGER-2/C:/Program Files/...."

But I don't understand why Gradle set $ sign in the path....

Comment: Can you tell who generates C:\Users\ponomarev\AppData\Local\Temp\ijinit6732759991667918700.gradle, and can you show its contents? Whoever generates this file gets it wrong. Perhaps try to edit the file and escape the `$`.

Comment: I can't insert contents of C:\Users\ponomarev\AppData\Local\Temp\ijinit6732759991667918700.gradle file to my first post. I don't know who generate this file :(

Comment: Might be an Android Studio bug. Have you tried to escape the `$`?

Comment: Yes, I'm tried. I manually replaced wrong paths "C$" to correct "C:", but after then I build the project IDE create new ijinit<many numbers>.gradle file with the same error inside.

Comment: I recommend to file an issue with Android Studio.